# How to assign value in JButton type byte array in java

Tags: java, user-interface, encryption

I’m trying to develop a system that will ask the user to enter a text in JTextBox (plainText) then it will click on key JButton (key_128) then it will encrypt the user text and show the output in another JTextBox(encryptedtext). the code now asking the user to enter the key. how i can change it to static value in JButton (key_128)

```
byte[]  plain = plaintext.getText().getBytes();
byte[] K = time_128.getText().getBytes();
byte[] encrypted = encrypt(plain, K);
String a = new String(bytesToHex(encrypted));
encryptedtext.setText(a);
```

Comment: You mean you want to show the `encrypted user input text` as JButton's text?

Comment: @ShuwnYuanTee No sir.instead of the user enter the key in textbox i want it to be in button the user just click on it then it encrypt the text that the user entered in textbox.